# Extending `ls` function

Tags: fish

Normally on Windows, I alias `ls` to

```
alias ls="ls -hNFCs --color=auto -I NTUSER.DAT\* -I ntuser.dat\*"
```

This removes the NTUSER.DAT files from my view when I `ls` my home directory along with setting some reasonable defaults.

However, doing the same with `fish`, I noticed my `.dircolors` are not being read.  It is because `ls.fish` loads up `.dircolors` but when I override it with the `alias` it loses that capability.

So my question is, how do I *extend* the default ls.fish just to add my extra parameters?

The closest thing I can do is copy the `ls.fish` file and modify the relevant portion

```
  function ls --description "List contents of directory" -V opt
            isatty stdout
            and set -a opt -F
            and set -a opt -hNFCs -I NTUSER.DAT\* -I ntuser.dat\*
            command ls $opt $argv
        end
```

Answer (score 3):

Just copying the function is indeed the thing to do. `funced ls` can help with this.

Adding a way to *extend* functions is much too easy to break - where do you allow extensions, how do you ensure arbitrary extensions don't break when you make a change,...

So just copying is nice and simple, especially for a function that's unlikely to be called anywhere else like `ls` (because you don't want to parse ls' output)

Comment: when using `funced ls` you actually lose the dircolors portion or am I missing that?

Comment: Ah, right, the dircolors bit is defined at source time in the function file, while `funced` will *only* edit the function. So you should probably either copy the entire file or just hardcode $LS_COLORS somewhere - in most cases it shouldn't change.

Comment: It's too bad `ls` is a function, if it wasn't then it can be aliased like normal with no side effects.  Perhaps it should just do the dircolors processing outside of the ls.fish file, but not sure how that would work.